# Backbone.js view fail to update

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, view, accordion, underscore.js

I was putting up a sample code for one of questions here on and i stumbled with this problem. I definitively know something simple is missing but can't reason out what. Rendering a simple collection does not show in the DOM but does during debugging in the console.Code is bit long(verbose) so did not want to replicate here. Have a jsfiddle please see that

#### JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zRSg3/2/

The views look like this:

```
/*Provides visual display of category*/
var categoryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template:_.template($("#categoryView").html()),
    className: "category-view",
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
        $(this.el).empty().html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }    
});

/*visual display of how categories looks*/
var categoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: "#accordian",
    render: function() {    
        this.collection.each(this.renderEach,this);
        return this;
    },
    renderEach: function(mod,index,arr) {
        $(this.el).empty().append(new categoryView({model:mod}).render().el);
    },
    events: {
        "load": "initAccordian"
    },
    initAccordian: function() {

    }
});
```

and they're rendered like this:

```
var userCategoriesView = new categoriesView({collection:userCategories});
userCategoriesView.render();​
```

Comment: @mu is too short any reason to include code here?

Comment: Questions should be complete in themselves, there's no guarantee that jsfiddle will keep your stuff around forever or that it won't be down when someone comes across your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you can't spell "accordion" (but neither can I so don't feel too bad):

```
el: "#accordian",
```

should be:

```
el: "#accordion",
```

Your next problem is that `renderEach` is clearing out all the HTML on each step through your collection so you'll end up with only the last element rendered:

```
renderEach: function(mod,index,arr) {
    $(this.el).empty().append(new categoryView({model:mod}).render().el);
},
```

Drop the `empty()` call:

```
renderEach: function(mod,index,arr) {
    $(this.el).append(new categoryView({model:mod}).render().el);
},
```

Another problem you'll have is that there is no `load` even on your `#accordion` so this:

```
events: {
    "load": "initAccordian"
},
```

won't do anything. You'll have to call `initAccordian` yourself (and you'll probably want to fix the spelling too); if you need to wait until the browser has control again before `initAccordion` is called then you could use a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a time of zero:

```
render: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.collection.each(this.renderEach,this);
    setTimeout(function() { that.initAccordion() }, 0);
    return this;
}
```

This "timeout of zero" hack is useful if you need the browser to get everything positioned and sized before you can finish your work.

Also, newer versions of Backbone provide a jQuery-ified version of `this.el` in [`this.$el`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-%24el) in your views so you don't need to `$(this.el)`.

Here's a cleaned up version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/EMMrD/

Answer (score 1):

You named gave the element the id `accordion` in the HTML but you passed the view `#accordian` as a selector. [Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buckdoyle/zRSg3/4/) with that tiny change.

Aside: might I suggest that you capitalise the variables you’re using to store the extended Backbone classes? Using lowercase makes it easy to mistake them for instances.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about pass `el` to the view's constructor.

Just change: `var userCategoriesView = new categoriesView({collection:userCategories});` to:

`var userCategoriesView = new categoriesView({collection:userCategories, el: $('#accordion')});`

Comment: did you notice this `var categoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({el: "#accordian",` Should i need to define `el` again through the constructor parameter ??